# Marketing API - get subscribers | unsubscribers | how to subscribe | unsubscribe

Tags: api, integration, php

I am new to SalesForce and I am having trouble locating the part of the documentation that refers to subscribing/unsubscribing someone via the API.

Could someone, Please, point me into the right direction as of how to:

1. Subscribe someone
2. Unsubscribe someone
3. Check if someone is subscribed
4. get all those who subscribed
5. get all those who unsubscribed

To speak more to the subject, I need the documentation that refers to the API method calls and parameters for the above actions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best resources would be the [Marketing Cloud Rest API](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api) documentation:

- [subscribe someone](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/subscribers/subscriber-create.html) and [manage subscribers on lists](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/managing-subscribers-on-lists.html)
- [unsubscribe someone](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/unsubscribing-and-logging-an-unsubevent-with-a-logunsubevent-execute-call.html)
- [Check if someone is subscribed](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/subscribers/subscriber-retrieve.html)
- [get all those who subscribed](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-all-subscribers-on-a-list.html) on a list
- [get all those who unsubscribed](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/tracking/unsubscribe-tracking.html) (unsubscribe tracking)

Comment: Hi, and thank you very very much for this information. As a followup question, is there any part in the DOCS with an example of how to do this via the REST API?

Comment: Hi Ares, there are some code samples in the documentation, just type 'sample' in the search bar. Have fun!

Comment: Hi, yes, but those are still SOAP examples... I was wondering more if there is a JSON REST example on how to subscribe/unsubscribe and so on... any thought on that?

Comment: if you have a e-mail address where we could elaborate this subject I would appreciate very much your assistance.

Comment: sfdc@techie.com

Comment: @Fred Need to update the links in your answer. They're all broken. ;)